# Requisição no postman (extensão chrome) funciona, mas com ajax não

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo uma requisição à uma API privada via POST. Primeiro fiz os testes via extensão Postman, ocorreu tudo bem.

Sem seguida fiz testes com a requisição via ajax e ele não funciona da mesma forma.

```
Restangular.oneUrl("app" , "meutoken").get().then(function (data){
    var tokenF = data; //aqui eu trago um token desta api, e ele realmente vem

    //aqui eu envio o POST
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "formulario",
        data : {
            nome : formulario.nome,
            email : formulario.email,
            telefone : formulario.telefone,
            assunto : formulario.assunto,
            mensagem : formulario.mensagem,
            tokenForm : tokenF
        },
        async : false,
        success : function (data){
            alert(data.mensagem)
        }
    });
});
```

Acompanhando pelo developer tools do chrome, vejo que todos os parametros foram enviados, porém a resposta do servidor é de que o `tokenF` não está sendo enviado, porém os outros campos sim.

Comment: Aparentemente a app Postman pode fazer pedidos CORS sem que o Browser o impeça. [Encontrei uma resposta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16021544/2256325) que fala sobre isso e aponta para uma [página de suporte do Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) onde refere como configurar uso de URLs fora do dominio.

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio. Vou tentar isto.